# c++ what happens when new/delete is replaced multiple times?

Tags: c++, new-operator

If I understand correctly, global replacement of operators `new`, `delete`, `new[]` and `delete[]` is something that happens at link time. So, if there is anywhere a replacement new compiled in any translation unit, it will be used for the entire compiled application. Some questions that arise from this:

1. is this statement correct?
2. what happens when there are replacements defined in multiple files? which one is used?
3. what happens with replacements defined in dynamically linked libraries?
4. is there a way to implement a replacement in terms of the version that is being replaced?

something like:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) {
  ... do something ...
  return previous_version_of_new(sz);
}
```

Comment: [See Global Replacements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: so, the answers to 1 is yes and the answers to 2-4 is the application will be ill-formed? is there at least a way for me to know if it's ill formed when I link in precompiled libraries?

Comment: Here is a real-world case.  Visual C++ in debug mode will `assert()` or crash if you attempt to override global `new`, and you happen use something like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You get a linker error if there are multiple strong symbols of the same name.

The allocator functions in the standard C and C++ libraries are defined to have weak linkage, and when the linker finds a symbol of that name with strong linkage, it will link against that strong symbol. I.e. this overriding of library supplied functions needs to be specifically allowed by the library; and this mechanism only has two levels, the weak and the strong level. And a second symbol at the strong level breaks linking.

What you *can* do when you implement `::operator new()`, is to rely on the C allocators instead. I.e. implement the C++ `::operator new()` in terms of the C `malloc()` function. This function set has a different symbol names, and thus remains accessible when you supply your own `::operator new()`. (The other approach would be to interact directly with the system kernel via `mmap()` to allocate whole pages to the process.)

---

You can see the type of the symbols with either `objdump -t` (weak symbols are printed with the `w` flag) or `nm` (be sure to use the `-D` flag on shared libraries, without it, only non-dynamic symbols are listed). If a library defines `::operator new()` or `malloc()` as a strong/normal symbol, that's the implementation that's going to be used.

Of course, libraries should never define a custom `::operator new()` or `malloc()` as a strong symbol unless they are specialized allocator libraries. Applications, on the other hand, may freely link in a custom allocator library, or ship their own version of `::operator new()` or `malloc()`, as they are the end users which define the complete set of available symbols.